# Facebook API 2.7 remove 'user_friends' permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm using the Facebook **API Graph 2.7** for my desktop application(this app was approved in 2016) just to post image on user timeline.

Now, Facebook notify me that i have to submit(again) my app to the review process because some permission policy are changed.

In particular, seems that i'm using the **'user_friends'** permission.

1. There is a  way to remove this permission from the list of permissions?

From the application dashboard seems that i **must** submit to the review(posting also a screencast) also if don't use 'user_friends' permission.

2. This permission was **'by default'**, before? I do not remember adding it in the permission list for the app approval.

Comment: of course you don´t submit user_friends if you don´t use it, that would be weird...what would they review in your app?

Comment: aaaah, you're right @luschn. i found the permission under the list "current permission" automatically and i was thinking that i must review the app. also because 'user_friends' is listed in the "approved item" but i do not add it in the past submission. However the red alert message say what you're saying  "If your app does not require the use of these permissions and features, no review is required, and no further action needs to be taken on your part."

Comment: I'm in puzzle too. For my app, in my approved permissions, it shows, email, public profile and user_friends. For user_friends, it says, "... This permission is approved by default. App Review Required: To retain access, please submit your app for review by August 1, 2018." But I'm not using user_friends anywhere in my app. So I do not need to submit for review, right?

Comment: @pravid Act quickly, our app's Login API use was just pulled/revoked without appeal. They said it was a faulty privacy policy, but it seems connected to use not submitting for review, even though we don't use any permissions which require review. user_friends is listed for us, but I'm pretty sure that's part of the minimum. Might be worth submitting and just saying "we don't use it".

Comment: @TahoeWolverine Thanks for notifying.
I checked in API updgrade tool for my app. It is showing migration from v2.8 to v3.1 and the method used is, "POST/pageid/feed". Also shows this message, "An error will now be thrown if 'picture', 'name', 'thumbnail' or 'description' params are specified using POST /{page-id}/feed for a URL that is not owned by the access token."
There is no mention specific to 'user_friends' permission.
Does that mean, I need to update Access token?

Comment: @TahoeWolverine We are in the same position and we cannot afford our Login API being revoked. We don`t use "user_friends" permission but it is still listed for us. How to submit a review request for REMOVING the "user_friends" permission and not getting blocked.

Comment: @TahoeWolverine you can answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808844/remove-user-friends-permission-under-facebook-developer-app-dashboard and i will accept it as answer.