# Remove "user_friends" permission under Facebook Developer App Dashboard

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

We are using Facebook Login for our Android app.

We have a custom button view for Facebook Login and the exact code we are using for logging with Facebook is:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
```

Both **"email"** and **"public profile"** permissions are approved by default.

We don`t need and also we are not using the **"user_friends"** permission or anything related to it.

Under the "**Facebook Developer App Dashboard** -> **App Review** - **My Permissions and Features**" section "user_friends" permission is listed.

Also, under "**Facebook Developer App Dashboard** -> **App Review** -> **Add Permissions and Features to Your Request**" section it is listed with Active status(Although the Request option is also present).

We want to remove this permission as we don't use it but we are unable to find a way to remove it. How can this be done?

Adding some screenshots which might help.

[image: My Permissions and Features]

[image: Add Permissions and Features to Your Request]

**Update:** 
**Additional info:**
We got a developer alert with a very short deadline. It doesn`t point out what exactly is wrong. So we are trying to find and fix any shortcomings. Alert ->

> In working to create a great Platform experience for everyone, we ask
>   developers to ensure the apps they build comply with our Platform
>   Policies. Your app xxxx (AppId: xxxxxxxxxx) doesn't comply with the
>   following:
>
> Platform Policy 1.2: Build an app that is stable and easily navigable.
>   Be sure your app insights reflect a positive experience.
>
> Here's a visual example of the policy:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/policy#1-1-photo.
>
> You can access the full list of our Platform Policies here:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/policy/.
>
> Please make the requested changes by 2019-02-24 at 12:00 PST.

Comment: it´s approved anyway, so why bother?

Comment: We got a developer alert with a very short timeline. It doesn`t point out what exactly is wrong. So we are trying to find and fix any shortcomings. Alert ->
In working to create a great Platform experience for everyone, we ask developers to ensure the apps they build comply with our Platform Policies. Your app xxxx (AppId: xxxxxxxxxx) doesn't comply with the following:

Platform Policy 1.2: Build an app that is stable and easily navigable. Be sure your app insights reflect a positive experience.

Comment: @binaryKarmic Did you figure this out?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini Nopes, but nothing happened to our application.